# infinite loop while building script for kernel

Tags: raspbian, kernel

I have replace 3.18 kernel with 3.10 kernel for some kernel module checking on raspbian.

Now when I tried to build that module I got error for kernel script (genkmsys, fixdep etc etc).

So, I tried to build the kernel script on raspbian (because CC is generating host version of executable), but it appears that the build is going on for a full day and I notice that it is building the same module over and over again.

My guess is that once it finishes it's build it checks the date or time, it gives the warning about clock skewing and mention that the build might be incomplete and repeat the building process over again.

So, is there any way to resolve this infinite building loop? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one way to solve this is to connect rpi to internet and use ntp to synchronize the clock.

After that the build perform as expected.

Other solution's are welcome.

Comment: for those who can't synchronize the clock -
try

    date -s "hh:mm:ss day MON YEAR" to set the date manually
e,g
    date -s "14:00:00 12th JAN 2006"